# Autocomplete text field doesn't open

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a text field and when the user enter some characters, a bloc appears and show some suggestions of results. I want count the number of suggestion, but I don't find how do that.

I can enter some characters via the CasperJS API, but impossible to get the content of the autocomplete bloc who appears. ("#ui-id-6")

My page test : 
http://www.spareka.fr/pieces_detachees_accessoires_electromenager

The form I want test is in the bloc "Recherche détaillée" at the top left. So, I must select a value for the first dropdown field ("Quel type d'appareil"), then I select a value in the second dropdown field ("Quelle marque?"). 
So, the third block "Quelle référence d'appareil" becomes actives and this is the autocomplete field I want test.

My sample code : (updated 18 October)

```
var casper = require("casper").create({});

casper.on("page.error", function(msg,trace){ //No message in the shell
    this.echo("error message : " + msg, "ERROR");
}); 
casper.on("remote.message", function(msg,trace){ //No message in the shell
    this.echo("remote message : " + msg);
});
casper.on("ressource.error", function(ressource){ //No message in the shell
    this.echo("ressource message errorCode : " + ressource.errorCode);
    this.echo("ressource message errorString : " + ressource.errorString);
    this.echo("ressource message errorUrl : " + ressource.url);
    this.echo("ressource message errorID : " + ressource.id);
});


casper.start("http://www.spareka.fr/pieces_detachees_accessoires_electromenager", function(){

// The first select "Quel type d'appareil"
this.then(function(){
    this.fillSelectors("form#search_form_4", {
        'select[id="finalProductType"]': 'Appareil à Fondue',
        }, true);
    });
    // No problem here

    // The second select "Quelle marque?"
    this.then(function(){
        this.fillSelectors("form#search_form_4", {
        'select[id="manufacturer"]': 'TEFAL',
        }, true);
    });
    // No problem here

    this.then(function(){
        this.sendKeys('#productReference', '*', {keepFocus: true}); //so, an element "ui-id-6" appear and in firebug, there are the suggestions of results
        this.capture("test88_screen01.png");

        //try with wait...
        /*
        this.wait(2000, function then(){ //error : No element matching selector found : #ui-id-6
            this.echo(this.getHTML("#ui-id-6").length); // wall of text
        });
        */

        this.waitUntilVisible("#ui-id-6", function(){ // error : Wait timeout of 5000ms expired, existing
            this.echo(this.getHTML("#ui-id-6").length);
        });

        this.echo(this.getHTML("#ui-id-6").length); //selector found (no error), but return 0
    });

    this.then(function(){
        this.capture("test88_screen02.png"); // very strange ! this screen shows the page after submitting the form, I don't understand, I didn't understand why the form is submited
        this.echo("end");
    });

});

casper.run();
```

My casper version : 1.1.0-beta3, and phantomjs : 1.9.7

Answer (score 1):

Wait works if you use its `then` callback. All `then*` and `wait*` casper step functions are asynchronous. That means that inside of a step, you should not call synchronous functions after other asynchronous functions.

```
this.then(function(){
    this.sendKeys('#productReference', '*', {keepFocus: true}); //so, an element "ui-id-6" appear and in firebug, there are the suggestions of results
    this.capture("screen01.png"); 

    //try with wait...
    this.wait(2000, function then(){
        this.echo(this.getHTML("#ui-id-6")); // wall of text
    });

    // or

    this.waitUntilVisible("#ui-id-6", function(){
        this.echo(this.getHTML("#ui-id-6"));
    });
});
```

Comment: Thx for your help =)
I try the "wait(2000)" but I get an error "No element matching selector found: #ui-id-6". And  "waitUntilVisible", I get "Wait timeout of 5000ms expired, existing". 
I don't understand because if in the "this.then" I write "this.echo("this.getHTML("#ui-id-6")", I haven't error, the selector is find but it return empty

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. What Casper/Phantom versions are you using? Is there some code that you removed? Try the code like it is in the question now with my fix.

Comment: My casper version : 1.1.0-beta3, and phantomjs : 1.9.0. I copy/paste your code, and I get the same errors... x) Ill update my new code in my first post.

Comment: Update PhantomJS to 1.9.7.

Comment: Casper version : 1.1.0-beta3 and phantomjs : 1.9.7. It is always the problem :/ line 26 ("this.echo(this.getHTML("#ui-id-6"));" in "wait(2000.." ), "No element matching selector found: #ui-id-6"

Comment: Its crazy x) 
http://s24.postimg.org/gp2vtv5kj/screen1.png
http://s28.postimg.org/cy0vwvk3f/screen2.png

Comment: I tried it on windows and rasbian (debian) and it works on both. Please register to the [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Maybe there are errors. You could also try the `ressource.*` events.

Comment: I add remote.message and page.error, but nothing change : 
http://s2.postimg.org/disy0fqc7/screen3.png .
Maybe I missused ? can you explain how I can use the ressourse.* ? Really thanks for help and your patience, Im a CasperJS newbies x)

Comment: I tried my code on Ubuntu (real OS, not virtualbox), and I get the sames errors (phatomjs 1.9.7, 1.1.0-beta3). Crazy crazy ... x)
You use the same code there is in my first post ?

Comment: Little changes so there is no wall of text: https://gist.github.com/artjomb/6b53d8f751975cda2f60 I'm using the same version as you. Maybe not every ressource is loaded. register `resource.error`: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-error

Comment: Im sorry, I don't have a goods news x) I tried with the error.ressource event but there aren't message in my shell...
I no longer know what to do :/
I update my last code in the first post